What is the best way of emulating a Ev3 brick?
The main goal: emulate the work of a EV3 brick so then I would use it as a part of the simulator.
The problem: I don't know the best way of doing this.
About a year ago I asked about the memory allocations in a Ev3 compiled program. Since then I haven't done anything more with this. And now I understand that this is quite a tedious way of emulating brick because I have to write my own "interpreter".
For now I have an idea just to run Pybricks or lms-2012 in a virtual machine with redirected IO (for ports, display, connections, buttons) but I am too witless to do this. For this approach, I would have just rewritten some parts of the original sources so the IO would be redirected to a socket or std. But even this is too hard for me because I am bad at C or ASM.
Then I found some repos where the emulator is already written: wheel, emulator toolkit, RoboSim:

As I understood the first one uses a virtual machine (VM) to emulate the EV3 but I can't understand how it works and why is there Java used (also not sure that this works with an old LEGO MINDSTORMS Ev3);
There is also a VM used (also not sure that this works with an old LEGO MINDSTORMS Ev3);
Probably custom "interpreter" for the LEGO bytecode (also not sure that this works with an old LEGO MINDSTORMS Ev3).

There is also the Virtual Robotics Toolkit that is not an open-source project and also uses a virtual machine (VM) to emulate Ev3. I couldn't decompile the library that works with the VM because it was compiled natively.
So for now the main question is: What is the best way to emulate the work of EV3 brick without having to write/rewrite a bunch of code?
Any help is appreciated, thanks!

After all the time I finally found a good way of emulating EV3 brick. I've tried different ways and this one is the best way I've found:

Bring the original or compat version of EV3 firmware;
Redirect some stuff to be exported (like motors data, sensors data, LCD buffers, buttons, etc.);


The firmware is written mostly on C lang, so for the step we can just export some methods to implement them outside the library


Compile the firmware as a library;


The compilation process of the firmware is done using CMake (useful tool for cross-compiling you code with configurable build steps). Change the output of the build to be a library and edit some other stuff (like dependencies that are presented only on *nix machines)


Import the library in an emulator application and configure redirected data.


In my case I used C# with Avalonia framework. Marshalled compiled library and implemented the redirected functions.

So I did the steps and got quite a good result (for now motor and sensor ports redirects are still under development):

Small clarifications about the project:

For now, the EV3 firmware library is only tested on Windows machines, but when I was rewriting it, I assumed it would be cross-platform;
It can be compiled and tested only targeting x86 because of some problems with pointer size. I've tried to deal with it but understood that there is too much work;
Output/input fuction implementations are still under development;
There are still some small bugs like I can't rename the brick;
Communication with the brick is also not done yet. I couldn't find any resources about emulating USB or Bluetooth. So probably only WiFi would be supported.

For those who are interested here is the source code

Thanks for the answer! While I can't test it to check its usefulness, it is clear that it works for you, which is great :) However, I guess others who would need this answer would not find it as intuitive as it is for you right now. Could you please take a few more minutes to add some more details to the listed steps?
